# Youtube upload from console + set copyright / license

Tags: youtube-data-api

I want to upload a video to Youtube from console. I found [youtube-upload](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-upload) which works fine, except that it doesn't show any way to set the license (I want to set the CC-BY license).

I also tried to tweak the script. But apparently, the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video) which the script uses doesn't provide any way to set the license.

Is there any other way to set the CC license when uploading a video from the console?

Answer (score 1):

You can update [status.license](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.license) = creativeCommon

as described. The code you are using is a python script, so you can try the official samples ([resumable_upload](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-python/blob/master/upload_video.py)). You will just add license = "creativeCommon" in [status](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-python/blob/master/upload_video.py#L101) dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, that sounded promising. I took the [upload_video.py](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-python/blob/master/upload_video.py), just changed the `status` dictionary definition to `status = dict(        privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus, license="creativeCommon")` but it had no effect. The license is still the Youtube standard license.

Comment: BTW: In the meantime, I found [googlecl](https://code.google.com/p/googlecl/), but without any documentation about setting the license. Do you maybe know if it's possible there?

Comment: At the end they all rely on the API. I'll check and let you know.